# Retrieve system cookies in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, cookies, laravel-5

In my old `php` code, I can get a `cookie` using

```
<?php echo json_encode($_COOKIE['basket']); ?>;
```

Now how can I do this in laravel.

All I want to do is something like this in my controller;

```
public function author ($) {
    // Get system cookie
    $cookie = retrieve a cookie
    return view('pages.blog.author', ['cookie' => $cookie]);
}
```

Then I can access it in my view.

FYI; the cookie I want to retrieve was not sent with the request. This is cookie that has been sent by visiting another page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [cookie](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/requests#cookies) facade. Sorry I don't find a link with laravel 5 but this example of laravel 4.2 work for me.
EDIT : change link

```
   use Cookie;  
    class myController { 
        public function myfunction {  
             $cookie = Cookie::get("cookie_name");  
        } 
     }
```